# jquery in visual studio 2012 ultimate and mvc 3

Tags: asp.net

i need to ask something and i am getting stucked of this:
This is my controller code :

```
        public ActionResult FastRegister(FormCollection collection)
    {
        UserModel db = new UserModel(0);
        string str = "";
        //Boolean 
        //Common.IsAlphaNumeric_Dot_Underscore()? er
        errorInsert err = new errorInsert();
        try
        {
            db.set_value(0, Common.HtmlFormUrlEncode(collection["user_name"]), Common.HtmlFormUrlEncode(collection["user_pass"]), "", "", Common.HtmlFormUrlEncode(collection["user_email"]), "", DateTime.Now, "", Common.RandomString(false), 0);
            db.Insert();
            err.duplicate = false;
            err.error = "success register";
            return Json(err, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

            if (exception.Message.Contains("unique") == true && exception.Message.Contains("duplicate") == true)
            {
                err.duplicate = true;
                err.error = "username or email already taken";
            }
            else
            {
                err.duplicate = false;
                err.error = exception.Message;
            }
            return Json(err, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
class errorInsert
{
    public Boolean duplicate;
    public string error;
    public errorInsert()
    {

    }

}
```

and this is my jquery code :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function ajax_send_url(user_name, user_pass, user_email)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/smile/User/FastRegister',
                data: 'user_name='+user_name+'&user_pass='+user_pass+'&user_email='+user_email,
                //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function(e)
                {
                    //var x=jQuery.parseJSON(e);
                    $("#loading").html(e.error);
                }
                , dataType:"json"
                , beforeSend:function (e){$("#loading").html('<img src="loading.gif" width="50px">');}

            });
        }
        $("#register").click
        (
            function()
            {
                var user_name = $("#user_name").val();
                var user_pass = $("#user_pass").val();
                var user_email = $("#user_email").val();
                ajax_send_url(user_name,user_pass,user_email );
            }
        );
    });
```

I've got in my firebug 200 OK Http but no response when i checked. Please someone figure it out and help me. Thanx...

Comment: Please anybody help me..